Proving a Fourier transform inequality for functions with mixed variable bounded support
I'm working on a problem involving the Fourier transform and have encountered an inequality that I am unsure how to prove. I would greatly appreciate any help or guidance you can provide.
Let $\gamma\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$ and $v\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\cap L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Also $\text{supp}\gamma(\cdot,\xi)\subset U$ and $|U|<+\infty$ for all $\xi\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Prove that there exist a constant $C=C(U)>0$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot))(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\leq C\Vert{\gamma}\Vert_{\infty}\left (\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|v(y)|dy\right),
\end{equation*}
where $\mathcal{F}$ denotes the Fourier transform on $L^2$.
Initially, I tried to use Plancherel's theorem, this is
\begin{equation}
\Vert \mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot)) \Vert_{L^2}=\Vert{\gamma (x,\cdot)v(\cdot)}\Vert_{L^{2}}
\end{equation}
and then use the hypothesis that $\gamma\in L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{2n})$. However, this idea is totally incorrect, since it is not possible to use plancherel in that case.

I have very hard time understanding your question, not least because the number of parentheses in your formula is odd...

@AlekseiKulikov, I edited it

There is a quadrillion reasons why this can't hold. To begin with, the scaling: left-hand side is quadratic in $\gamma$ and $v$ while the right-hand side is linear (should there be a square root on the left-hand side?) Second of all, if you do use plancherel, as you planned, then you essentially want to bound the $L^2$-norm of the compactly supported function by its $L^1$-norm, which is also not possible. Please, carefully examine whether this is really what you want or not, and if it is I can post an answer.

@AlekseiKulikov, You're right, I had a typing error on the left side.

The idea of ​​the problem is that for this case it is not possible to apply Plancherel, since it depends on two variables, however it is possible to find an estimate

"however it is possible to find an estimate" -- do you mean you have a proof? Then why did you ask the question in the first place? And as I said I think it is just not true...

I don't have a proof, I have to prove it. I found it in some notes where he states that it is true, he says that to prove that is to try to imitate Plancherel's proof.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood the question, but isn't this just
$$
|\mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot))(x)|
= |\mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot))(x)| \mathbb{1}_{U}(x)
\leq \Vert \gamma(x, \cdot) v(\cdot) \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \mathbb{1}_{U}(x)\\
\leq \Vert \gamma\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{2n})} \Vert v \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} \mathbb{1}_{U}(x)
$$ and therefore
$$
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot))(x)|^{2}dx\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
\leq \vert U\vert^{1/2} \Vert \gamma\Vert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^{2n})} \Vert v \Vert_{L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)} 
$$?

How did you get the very first equality? When you take the Fourier transform, the support does not stay the same...

@AlekseiKulikov Isn't $\gamma(x, \cdot) = 0$ for $x \notin U$ by assumption of OP?

Oh, I interpreted this line differently. Yes, if you look at it this way you are correct.

@AlekseiKulikov Yeah I think the assumption is written down in a confusing way.

@unwissen,Can you explain the first inequality to me?

@JulianBejarano https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#On_L1

@unwissen, The x where the transform is calculated is the same where the function $\gamma$ is evaluated, which is fixed, I think that causes a problem

@JulianBejarano I don't think so or you really have to explain your notation. You still have the same pointwise bound $|\mathcal{F}(\gamma(x,\cdot)v(\cdot))(x)| = \left\vert \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \mathrm{d}\xi , \gamma(x, \xi) v(\xi) e^{2\pi i x \xi}  \right\vert \leq  \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \mathrm{d}\xi ,  \left\vert \gamma(x, \xi) v(\xi) e^{2\pi i x \xi} \right\vert = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  \mathrm{d}\xi  \left\vert ,\gamma(x, \xi) v(\xi) \right\vert = \Vert \gamma(x, \cdot) v(\cdot) \Vert_{L^1}$.
